# Upgrade Hard Drive - Keep domain membership?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-7, hard-drive, cloning

If I upgrade my laptop hard disk by cloning it to an SSD with PartedMagic will my computer fall out of the domain to which it is a currently a member?

Doing some Google searching and it doesn't look like the machine SID changes when cloning but I wanted to confirm that this is enough to keep it in the domain. Any extra information on domain membership is appreciated as well! Domain is on Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 4):

The domain membership will remains as the system will be presented the same way.
The SID is a set of information saved in different places.
The problem starts if you want to use this disk image to create multiple pc. There you will have to faces difference problems such as drivers and renewal of SID.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Cloning and replacing the system disk will not affect the trust relationship with the domain, no